# How to remove html part from filtering datatable jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I working with datatable library, and i have issues, i have filtering system, and in case if in `<td>` i have some html code, for ex:  `<a hreff="#">TD name</a>` i will have in column some part from html:

In JSFiddle if u will select **Station code > Create Filter** u will see the HTML code in filtering result.

[image]

Code example u can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g6e8xtpy/).

Some how i need to remove html code from fitering result, how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

replace the html tag in the td and draw it.

```
render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
  return data.replace(/<(\/)?([a-zA-Z]*)(\s[a-zA-Z]*=[^>]*)?(\s)*(\/)?>/g, '');
}
```

Add your function addSpliting

```
function addSpliting(val) {
  if(val != '') {
  
  $("#test1").DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    searchPanes: {
      layout: 'columns-4',
    },
    columnDefs: [{
      searchPanes: {
        show: true,
      },
      targets: '_all',
      render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
        return data.replace(/<(\/)?([a-zA-Z]*)(\s[a-zA-Z]*=[^>]*)?(\s)*(\/)?>/g, '');
      }
    }],
    dom: 'Pfrtip'
  });
  $('.dtsp-searchPanes').children().each(function(i, obj){
            if(!val.includes(i)) $(this).hide();
    else $(this).show();

});
```

[image]